# Installation kit modified during install. Is this a security issue?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, security, dd, usb-installation

I use to create my usb stick install kit with:

```
# dd if=downloads/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdd
```

and it worked for me.

I also use to verify the install kit before and after install with:

```
# cmp downloads/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sdd
```

and this also worked for me until now. It exits with end of file error, because the kit is shorter than `/dev/sdd`.

Now, however, for the first time, there is a difference after install at byte 480, line 4.

The kit has been created on a compromised system.

However, I have doubts that it has been modified by malicious code.

So I ran:

```
# mount /dev/sdd1 mnt
# mount -o loop ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso mnt1
# find mnt/ -exec bash -c 'file={}; cmp $file ${file/mnt/mnt1}' \; | grep differ
```

and found no difference, only that cmp does not compare directories.

```
# lsblk -fm /dev/sdd
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT  SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdd  iso966 Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64
│                 2020-07-31-16-51-12-00                                          7,2G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdd1
│    iso966 Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64
│                 2020-07-31-16-51-12-00                                          2,6G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdd2
│    vfat         C26E-047E                                                       3,9M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdd3
     ext4   writable
                  a83a9b1c-36cb-4312-9aba-0359f74c0374                            4,7G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

What could be the cause?
Should I worry about this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2020-September/018786.html

(Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 20.)